# Restricting the bounds of an associated type of a supertrait

Tags: rust

I am trying to make the following (simplified) design work:

```rust
trait Api {
    type BufferType: Buffer;
    type TextureType: Texture;
}

trait ApiObject {
    type ApiType: Api;
}

trait Buffer: ApiObject
    where ApiType: Api<BufferType = Self> {
    
}

trait Texture: ApiObject 
    where ApiType: Api<TextureType = Self> {
}
```

However, this results in the following errors:

```rust
error[E0412]: cannot find type `ApiType` in this scope
  --> src/lib.rs:11:11
   |
11 |     where ApiType: Api<BufferType = Self> {
   |           ^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0412]: cannot find type `ApiType` in this scope
  --> src/lib.rs:16:11
   |
16 |     where ApiType: Api<TextureType = Self> {
   |           ^^^^^^^ not found in this scope
```

I also tried `trait Buffer: ApiObject<ApiType = Api<BufferType = Self>>`, but that doesn't seem to be valid rust either.

How can I set an associated type in `ApiType` to `Self` when it is part of a supertrait?

Comment: You might want to use `type F : Foo` instead of confusing the names here.

Comment: As an extension of confusing names, the error you see is from `where Api: ...` being interpretted as the trait and not the associated type. Use `Self::Api` for that, but you still get a (different) error.

Comment: I feel a bit hurt you're invested enough to put a bounty but not enough to address my comment: the error presented is because `Api` means the `trait` and not the associated `type` in `ApiObject`. If you [change it](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f93447c84a6b02dfe53a57fb984f72c5) to `type: ApiType: Api` and use `where ApiType: ...` below, you can see the *"cannot find type `ApiType` in this scope"* error. To use the associated type, you *need* to use `Self::`. I made a comment and not an answer since it doesn't solve the issue, but I urge to to fix that.

Comment: @kmdreko I appreciate the help, but I don't know how to continue from your suggested changes. It still does not let me do what I want to do (set an associated type in `Api` to `Self`). The bounty is to hopefully get someone to who can get to a solution. I will update the question to use the `ApiType` name as that generates more accurate errors

Comment: You're still not understanding, you *need* to write `Self::ApiType` to use the associated type, simply `ApiType` doesn't work. See [this code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=279421fb58326355eeb59b3dd8e129b3) which expresses what you are attempting. It still yields an error that I hope you can get an answer to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the `Self::` prefix to the `where` clause while also setting `ApiType` to `Self` for all `ApiObject`s in `Api` fixes the compilation errors:

```rust
trait Api {
    type BufferType: Buffer<ApiType = Self>;
    type TextureType: Texture<ApiType = Self>;
}

trait ApiObject {
    type ApiType: Api;
}

trait Buffer: ApiObject
where
    Self::ApiType: Api<BufferType = Self>,
{
}

trait Texture: ApiObject
where
    Self::ApiType: Api<TextureType = Self>,
{
}
```

Comment: Looks promising! I'll try it out in the real thing soon to see if I run into any limitations

Comment: While it compiles, try to actually use it... It does not work as expected.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Seems to work just fine for me, could you clarify what is wrong with it?

Comment: @RickdeWater Like this: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ce7e249972dbc95ecb14b18a7c746791. You need to repeat yourself like this: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=78c1839ea4dd4b1f8aa05afb0d2a79bd.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Ah I see, generics are a bit verbose. In this design however you are never supposed to use `Buffer` or `Texture` as generics, instead you always use `Api` to get the type of any object that you need. Otherwise a function like `fn foo<B: Buffer, T: Texture>() {}` could not guarantee that the two can actually interact. You wouldn't want to be able to pass a `VulkanBuffer` and a `D3D12Texture` to that function.

Comment: @RickdeWater Technically, you can constrain them, for example: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e0bb15bb0b519c9bb408590eba506d05. But if you don't plan to use them as standalone generic parameters, why do you need the bounds on them? The bounds on `Api` ought to be enough.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman There were a couple of places where those bounds were not enough, and the compiler did not know whether traits really referenced to the same type. This happened a lot with `Device`, which is referenced by most objects, as well as `Memory`, which can be bound to `Texture`s and `Buffer`s.

Comment: The following example would not work without the bounds: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5d0b4c127f4883b5014a3b16f6651890